# Spring MVC View

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What are you guys using for your view in Spring MVC.
I know Spring MVC has a wide support for views but I'm having trouble finding what works well, what view to use when, etc.

Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 6):

JSP, of course.

Sometimes PDF; Excel when necessary.

BlazeDS makes Flex integration with Spring possible.  That's a great way to go if you use Flex.

"...I'm having trouble finding what works well..." - they all work well from Spring's point of view.

What to use when?  Use the technology that *you* know best.  Spring can deal with all of them just fine.

UPDATE: Since this was written *three years ago*, I'll amend it by saying that I would recommend just using Velocity templates to marry with dynamic data.  Templates should use HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery.  I think that provides the best flexibility you can have.  You "future proof" your design if you can generate responsive HTML 5 pages.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the following templating languages

[Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html): Most of our old projects are using apache velocity to render the view. This is a very easy to learn and use language. But here xml operations are very limited.

[Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/): Now we are migrating our project to Freemarker. This is a very good templating language. Advantage over velocity is that it has a very good support for xml data processing

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsp with struts tiles to give good and uniform experience. You can refer to "Spring in Action" Book to find out how to do it. I have used this combination for developing my website www.propertymela.net. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Thymeleaf, because it has static prototyping which is very useful when there are two teams doing web design and server side development. I believe JSP is a fairly old technology, and I've had some problems with using HTML5 with it, which is why I opted to use a different view technology.

Also, Velocity is a competitor of Thymeleaf but I haven't really touched on Velocity aside from creating email templates.

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is my option. JSTL has all the functional component which we can achieve through the use of scriplets in JSP. The avoidance of the scriptlet code in JSP is key to move into JSTL

In scriplet code if anything wrong whole page breaks. But it is not in the case of JSTL